# Failed to configure iptables FORWARD

Tags: networking, linux-mint, iptables

My goal is to simulate "packet loss" in the network, using "iptables".

My target configuration:

1. Linux Mint 18.3 laptop serving as Wireless Access Point. 
   `uname -a` output is:
   `Linux max-Latitude-7490 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)`
2. Two Android devices, connecting to the access point, and communicating using IPv4 (UDP or TCP)

Unfortunately, while I was able to control the traffic between the 1st Android and the laptop using 'iptables' INPUT chain, it turns out that the FORWARD chain doesn't affect the IP traffic between the two Android devices.

I put "DROP" default policy on the FORWARD chain, and no other rules.
So the output of `sudo iptables -L` looks like:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Unfortunately, the traffic between the devices connected to the Access Point wasn't blocked.

Again, the issue is with FORWARD: INPUT chain rules worked well.

Any hint on how to resolve / debug further will be appreciated!

Comment: I don't expect that traffic between two devices connected to one access point even reaches the network stack of the access point. As they are on the same network, forwarding is not relevant.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to follow the advice of this article: https://serverfault.com/questions/201588/configuring-a-router-to-drop-packets-introduce-latency-corrupt-data . What should I do in order to be the "router" mentioned there? Thanks.

Comment: That article is talking about using a router to disturb the flow of traffic. To have a router in the mix, then you need the two devices to be on separate networks. This could be two different SSIDs on the wifi network with each its own subnet.

Comment: Thanks. So based on your expert understanding... if I connect one Android device via WiFi Access Point exposed by a Linux host, and another Android device via Ethernet cable to the same Linus host - 'iptables' FORWARD will affect the traffic between the 2 Androids? Tnx.

Comment: Only if the ethernet and wifi networks are different subnets, otherwise the networks will be bridged and not routed.